# hot to get Thread results to TextArea

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 4 classes, one GUImain(observer), one subject, 2 classes implementing Runnable.
The subject class starts 2 threads which are coded in the classes implementing Runnable.
Thread 1 - should access each Order of an Arraylist, send the Order to the subject class and then notify the observer to be appended on to a TextArea.

please tell how this can be accomplished..

Some more details about the implementation so far:

GUIMain Class: JTextArea (to be filled with Orders from an ArrayList)

Kitchen class: Thread run() implemented here:
- Get each Order from the OrderList ( a list of 25 orders read from an input file)
- send it to the subject class - so that the GUIMain(observer) can update itself.
- the JTextArea should be appended by only a few orders at a time.

```
public class Kitchen implements Runnable{
private Restaurant R;
private OrderList Orders; 
public Kitchen()
{
Orders = new OrderList(); 
}
private String getOrderReport()
{
String report=" ";
report = Orders.OrderDetailsReport();
return report;
}
@Override
public void run() {
System.out.println("inside kitchen thread");
String report=" ";
try
{
Thread.sleep(100);
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Kitchen thread exception" + e.getStackTrace());
}
System.out.println(getOrderReport());
System.out.println("size of OL from kitchen thraed:"+Orders.getListSize());
System.out.println(R.getListOfOrders());
} 
}
output:
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at REST.Kitchen.run(Kitchen.java:41)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Please give us more details including what you have so far, what you've tried, where you're stuck... As written, your question is very broad, perhaps overly broad, making it difficult for me to answer. Also, is this a Swing GUI question? Are you working with JTextAreas and not TextAreas?

Comment: :) Thanks a ton for the quick response !! I would like to show what i have done so far but there are around 10-12 classes. how can i send it to you??

Comment: What you will want to do is to extract the key code and post it here. In fact you should consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please remember that we're all volunteers who you're asking free advice from, and we won't have the time to look at 10-12 classes worth of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the details of your setup it's difficult to say. It sounds like your close to a model/view/controller setup, but you don't have a unifying model.

Usually the view/rendering thread (your GUIMain) is also a separate thread, that checks the model your (sounds like a combination of your runnable classes) and updates itself.

Simple solution would be to make the GUIMain another thread that takes your runnable classes in the constructor. It would then pole the runnable classes and update the textarea as needed...

PS. make sure you include a Thread.sleep() for some period in all threads, or it will require a lot of RAM to run

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I tried and that bit is working now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check off verified for my answer... I have to increase my rep so I can post comments :-)